# How can I store the text entered by the user into a variable?

Tags: python

The task is: there is a database in sqlite, let's say in the following format:

```
ID - Name - Price - Shop
1 - Milk - 3.5 - Testshop
2 - Banana - 2.3 - Testshop2
3 - Water - 0.5 - Testshop
```

I am trying to write a telegram bot (using telebot, pytelegrambotapi) that allows you to view this list and edit it in the DB. At the moment, I can get all the records, as well as ask the user for the ID of the line that he would like to edit, for example:

```
Bot: Enter the line number to edit:
User: 1
Bot: What parameter do you want to change?
User: /Price
Bot: Enter new value:
User: 1.1
```

`cur.execute ("UPDATE products SET name = {} WHERE id = {}". format (name, id))`

Further, if the user wants to continue to change this list, for example, change the name of the store, then there is no need to ask him for the ID again, he must save somewhere, that is, the user simply enters, for example, the command / shop and edits the same line (with number 1) and changes the shop parameter to something else.

Here's an example from my file:

```
def change_options(name, id):
    try:
        cur.execute("UPDATE products SET name = {} WHERE id = {}".format(name,id))
        conn.commit()
        return print("OK")
    except:
        return print("Error!")
```

Telegram bot code:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['options_list'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(get_all_lists_name()))
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Enter # list')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, get_list_options)

def get_list_options(message):
    id = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(get_all_options(id))) # ID From User
```

And now, i don't know, how i can change options:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['milk'])
def change_milk(message):
    change_options(milk, id) #Where i can get this id, from "def get_list_options(message):"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(get_all_lists_name()))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'milk changed')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['banana'])
def change_banana(message):
    change_options(banana, id) #Where i can get this id, from "def get_list_options(message):"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(get_all_lists_name()))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'banana changed')
```

I apologize for the possibly incorrect presentation, I tried to explain as much as possible, thanks for your answers!

Comment: I would assume that the `message` parameter contains the message text in some attribute (`message.text`? I'm not familiar with telegram's API). You could then parse it like any other string, probably

Comment: As far as I understand, each "message_handler" has this variable "its own", it is not global.

Comment: oh, you mean you want to reference the previous prompts to the same user? Ideally you'd have them provide all the necessary information in a single command. Otherwise, you could use a `dict` with the key being the user, and the value being some structure that contains the current state of the user's request.